# How to sort tableView from A-Z swift 2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, sorting

I have a simple array of `names` in a `tableView` and i would like to sort the `tableView` from A-Z when i will press a dedicated `button`.

## **TableViewController.Swift**:

```
import UIKit
    
class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate{
    
@IBOutlet var tableViewController: UITableView!
        
// MARK : Data
        
var names = ["Shalvata",
             "Markid",
             "Litzman Bar",
             "The Cat & The Dog",
             "Light house"]
```

And it looks like this :

[image]

I would like to implement a `button` that once pressed the `names Array`  in the `tableView` will be sorted from A-Z & when i press again it will return back to default order.

Thank you

Comment: You'll wan to sort your data source, the array and reload the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need first create a class variable to indicate if sorted or not yet. then create sorted array

```
// this is class variable
var isSorted = false
let names = ["Shalvata",
         "Markid",
         "Litzman Bar",
         "The Cat & The Dog",
         "Light house"]

var sortedNames = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sortedNames = names.sort()

    // your other lines of codes

}
```

Then in function if button is clicked update this `sorted` variable to return sort in tableView `cellForRow` method

```
if isSorted {
    // use the sortedNames here
}
else {
    // use normal names array
}
```

Your button Action function will be like this.

```
func onClickButton() {
     isSorted = !isSorted // change value of isSorted either to false or true depends on last updated value
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I get This error : `Instance member 'names' cannot be used on type TableViewController'`

Comment: @NewbieQuestions I updated the class variable. this should solve that error. sorting should be done in viewdidload

Comment: Now i get this error:`Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

Comment: Please specify the error at which line. My solution there should work but you need change a bit to fit your current code

Comment: Both errors were on the same line which is : `sortedNames = names.sorted()`

Comment: Yeah forgot that `sorted` should be `sort` in swift 2.3. I changed the code above